# Filtering from selected input in R shiny

Tags: filter, shiny, flexdashboard, selectinput

I keep getting errors when trying to filter a data base according to a selected input. I made this really simple example based on the iris dataset to show you guys my problem:

````
    ```{r}
    library(flexdashboard)
    library(tidyverse)
    ```
    
    Sidebar {.sidebar}
    =====================================
    
    ```{r}
    
    fluidRow(
      column(7,
             selectInput("Species", "Choose a species",
                         choices = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"))))
    
    mydata <- reactive({
    iris %>% filter(Species == input$Species)
    })
    
    ```
    
    Results
    ===================================== 
    
    ```{r}
    head(mydata)
    ```
````

Comment: `mydata` is a reactive, so it has to be evaluated with `mydata()`

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure if I get it, could you please write the code down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `mydata` is a reactive, you have to evaluate it with `mydata()` in a reactive context (e.g. `renderDT`). For more information, see [flexdashboard with shiny](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/shiny.html) and [a shiny tutorial](https://mastering-shiny.org/).

````
---
title: "test"
runtime: shiny
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
  orientation: columns
vertical_layout: fill
theme: bootstrap
---
  

    ```{r global, include = FALSE}
    
    library(flexdashboard)
    library(tidyverse)
    library(DT)
    
    ```
    
    Sidebar {.sidebar}
    =====================================
    
    ```{r}
    
    fluidRow(
      column(7,
             selectInput("Species", "Choose a species",
                         choices = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"))))
    
    mydata <- reactive({
    iris %>% filter(Species == input$Species)
    })
    
    ```
    
    Results
    ===================================== 
    
    ```{r}
    renderDT({head(mydata())})
    ```
````

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help. But if instead of showing the dataset, as in my example, I use it to make some more analysis, like calculate the mean of Sepal.Lenght `mean(mydata$Sepal.Lenght)`, how could I do it?

Comment: again, use `mydata()$Sepal.Length` in a reactive context, e.g. a reactive: `new_data <- reactive({mean(mydata()$Sepal.Lenght)})`. Have a look at the tutorials I've linked

Comment: Thank you again, I appreciate it.